# Google Assistant sdk GRPC authentication error : io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED:

Tags: grpc, google-assistant-sdk, grpc-java, google-assist-api

I successfully created EmbeddedAssistantStub using the below code.

```
EmbeddedAssistantGrpc.EmbeddedAssistantStub mAssistantService = EmbeddedAssistantGrpc.newStub(channel)
                                  .withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(
                                            Credentials.fromResource(mClientId,mRefreshToken,mAccessToken)
                                   ));
```

After this i passed audio data to StreamObserver, At that time below exxception was occured.

```
Line 3378: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
Line 3378: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
Line 3379: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:540)
Line 3380: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:392)
Line 3381: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:428)
Line 3382: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:76)
Line 3383: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:514)
Line 3384: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:431)
Line 3385: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
Line 3386: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
Line 3387: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:152)
Line 3388: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
Line 3389: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
Line 3390: 12-07 12:59:25.099  1917  4286 E  GASample:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

After this no response from response observer.

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They messed up with their backend. Just wait until they fix it. Here is the github thread regarding that bug:
https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/138

Answer (score 0):

They fixed this issue at back-end.

@JHorseman : Thanks for the support.