# Google Assistant SDK refusing authenticated channel as "UNAUTHENTICATED"

Tags: oauth, kotlin, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to create a Google Assistant for my Raspberry Pi in Kotlin. I implemented a OAuth flow using the so called "device flow" proposed in [this IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow-07), since my Raspberry shall later just expose a web interface and does not have any input devices or graphical interfaces.

Google does support this flow (of course) and I obtain a valid access token with user consent in the end. For testing purpose I also tried a default authorization flow that will just forward the user to localhost, as it is normally done but it did not solve the problem.

I tested the access token using [this tool](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/oauth2/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo) and it confirmed validity of scope and token. So the token itself should work.

Scope is: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/grpc/integrate)
This actually does not point to any valid web resource but is referenced in every documentation.

Then I tried to stream audio data to the assistant SDK endpoint using the gRPC provided java stubs. As took a third party [reference implementation](https://github.com/mautini/google-assistant-java-demo/) as a guide how to authenticate the rpc stub. But neither the reference implementation nor my own one works. They both report

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

The stub is authenticated this way:

```
embeddedAssistantStub.withCallCredentials(
            MoreCallCredentials.from(OAuth2Credentials
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setAccessToken(
                            myAccessToken,
                            myAccessTokenExpirationDate))
                    .build()))
```

and the authenticated request is performed like this:

```
val observer = authenticatedEmbeddedAssistantStub.converse(myStreamObserverImplementation)
observer.onNext(myConfigConverseRequest)
while(more audio data frames available) {
    observer.onNext(myAudioFrameConverseRequest)
}
observer.onCompleted()
```

(I prefixed pseudo variables with "my" for clarity, they can consist of more code in the actual implementation.)

I even contacted the author of this demo implementation. He told me, last time he checked (several months ago) it was working perfectly fine. So I finally ran out of options.
Since the client implementation I took as reference used to work and I do actually authenticate the stub (although the error message suggests the opposite) Probably, either my valid access token with correct scope is not suitable chosen for the assistant API (though I followed the suggestions of google) or the API servers had a change not properly documented in the [getting started articles](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/grpc/) by google.

So: Did anyone ran in the same problem and know how to fix it? I have the project on github. So if anyone needs the broken source code, I can do a temporary commit that produces the error.

Note, to save some works for mods: This issue referres to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697554/statuscode-unauthenticated-google-assistant-windows-10) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696329/google-assistant-sdk-grpc-authentication-error-io-grpc-statusruntimeexception) question, both unresolved and using different languages but describing a similar problem.

Comment: It seems others are also currently experiencing issues with this: https://plus.google.com/114306113999433581153/posts/Rfy4bJ7F8sy They may have broken something in their recent deploy: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/12/OAuth-whitelisting-can-now-control-access-to-GCP-services-and-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems I was right about my second assumption: The error is server side. Here is the github issue, let's just wait for the fix.

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/138